# can't console log state from reducer function?

Tags: reactjs, console.log, reducers, use-reducer

I cannot figure out why the state isn't changing with this reducer function setup in React. I just want to console log the new state from the reducer function?

```
const [lessonState, dispatchLesson] = useReducer(lessonReducer, {
    lesson: 0,
    isComplete: false,
  });

const lessonReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "UPDATE") {
    return { lesson: action.lesson, isComplete: true };
  }
};

const initializeLesson = () => {
    dispatchLesson({ type: "UPDATE", lesson: 2 });
    console.log(lessonState);<------
};
```

```
//other stuff//
export default function Dashboard() {

  useEffect(() => {
    context.initializeCourse();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="dashboard">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue or you just want to see the reducer state after dispatching it immediately ?

Comment: I just want to see the updated state, I am learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get updated reducer state after dispatching it immediately. To get the update state data you can do following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("lessonState", lessonState);
  }, [lessonState]);
```

So when state is updated, this useEffect will be triggered and you will get your updated state.

Comment: So it is updating technically then?